# Inconveniente con funcion Switch en RStudio

Tags: r

Cordial saludo, necesito pedirles por favor su amable colaboracióncon la función Switch en el lenguaje R,
tengo el siguiente código en donde por medio de una edad solicitada  me imprima la etapa de la vida que esta viviendo, el código es el siguiente:

```
install.packages("svDialogs") # Para instalar el paquete
library(svDialogs)            # Para usar el paquete


edad<- dlgInput(message="Ingrese su edad: ")$res
edad  <- as.integer(edad) 
  edad= switch(edad, (edad<0), print("Usted no ha nacido"),  
        (edad>0 & edad<=12), print("Usted esta en la etapa de la niñez"),
        (edad>12  & edad<18),print("Usted esta en la etapa de la adolescencia"),
        (edad>18  & edad<=40),print("Usted esta en la etapa de la adultez joven"),
        (edad>40  & edad<=60),print("Usted esta en la etapa de la madurez"),
        (edad>60),print("Usted esta en la tercera edad"),
        )
```

al ejecutar el código me muestra el siguiente error:

Error: duplicate 'switch' defaults: '(edad < 0)' and 'print("Ust...

Muchas gracias de antemano por cualquier colaboración.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El principal problema es que el `switch()` no funciona como lo estás suponiendo, esta función solo evalúa una sola vez la expresión, por ejemplo:

```
variable <- 2
switch(variable, 
       "Es 1", "Es 2", "Es 3")

[1] "Es 2"
```

Para lo que buscas necesitas una construcción más compleja, mediante múltiples `if()`:

```
if (edad <= 0) {
  print("Usted no ha nacido") 
} else {
  if (edad >= 0 & edad <= 12) {
    print("Usted esta en la etapa de la niñez")
  } else {
    # Y as+i con el resto de las condiciones
  }
}
```

O de una forma más compacta:

```
estado <- if (edad <= 0) "Usted no ha nacido" else 
            if (edad >= 0 & edad <= 12) "Usted esta en la etapa de la niñez" else
               if (edad>12 & edad<18) "Usted esta en la etapa de la adolescencia" else
                 if (edad>18 & edad<=40) "Usted esta en la etapa de la adultez joven" else
                   if (edad>40 & edad<=60) "Usted esta en la etapa de la madurez" else
                     if (edad>60) "Usted esta en la tercera edad"

print(estado)
```

Sino puedes usar `case_when()` del paquete `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

estado <- case_when(
            edad <= 0 ~ "Usted no ha nacido",
            edad >= 0 & edad <= 12 ~ "Usted esta en la etapa de la niñez",
            edad >12 & edad < 18 ~ "Usted esta en la etapa de la adolescencia",
            edad >18 & edad <= 40 ~ "Usted esta en la etapa de la adultez joven",
            edad > 40 & edad <= 60 ~ "Usted esta en la etapa de la madurez",
            edad > 60 ~ "Usted esta en la tercera edad"
)
print(estado)
```